# Lighttpd proxy redirect by port

Tags: proxy, lighttpd

I'm really just starting out with lighttpd and I'm not sure how to configure this exactly.

I'm wanting to take traffic and redirect to another server say "http://localhost/url_a/" and redirect the request and responses from that to "http://other_server:8080/"

Another example would be "http://localhost/url_b/" going to "http://other_server:8081/url_b/"

What exactly should I look into for accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a redirect (i.e. send the client to the other location), or do you want to proxy (Lighttpd connects to the other location and sends the response to the client)?

Comment: I'd like more of a proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lighttpd 1.4 you need to use [mod_proxy](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy) to forward the request to another server.

```
proxy.server = ("/url_a" => ((
    "host" => "1.2.3.4",
    "port" => 8080,
)))
```

Changing the URL path or virtual hostname is a bit tricky in 1.4. If you're using 1.5 you can use [mod_proxy_core](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxyCore) instead, which is more configurable:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/url_a" {
    proxy-core.protocol = "http"
    proxy-core.backends = ("other_server:8080")
    proxy-core.rewrite-request = (
        "_uri" => ( "^/url_a/?(.*)" => "/$1" ),
        "Host" => ( ".*" => "other_server" ),
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm currently limited to using only 1.4. Since 1.5 isn't compiling very well.