# Serve ports through URL using lighttpd

Tags: port, lighttpd

### Settings and goal

On a raspberry pi, I'm running a Lighttpd server (version: lighttpd/1.4.53 (ssl)). This server was initially installed by [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/), a DNS I'm starting to use to manage my network. I already managed to associate `http://raspi.home` to my raspberry pi IP.

This device already runs several services, for instance an [R-shiny server](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) on port 3838 and a [homeassistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) installation on port 8123, that I can thus access through `http://raspi.home:3838/` and `http://raspi.home:8123` respectively.

My goal is now to be able to access my services through user-friendly addresses, such as  `http://raspi.home/shiny` (port 3838) and `http://raspi.home/homeassistant` (port 8123).

Since the lighttpd server was configured for pi-hole, `/var/www/html/` contains only two folders: "pihole" and "admin". I can access pi-hole admin panel through `http://raspi.home/admin` and `http://raspi.home/pihole` is accessible but not of much use.

**My goal is to make that browsing `http://raspi.home/shiny/...` serves `http://raspi.home:3838/...` (and same for homeassistant).**

### Advance so far

I'm modifying `/etc/lighttpd/external.conf`, which adds on `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` (code [here](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/blob/master/advanced/lighttpd.conf.debian)). I tried various things but lighttpd conf files are quite confusing to me, and I'm never sure what should I put at the root level or in a `$HTTP["url"]`.

What worked the most so far was adding an URL mapping with the server definition:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/shiny" {
    proxy.header = (
        "map-urlpath" => ( "/shiny" => "/" ),
        "upgrade" => "enable"
    )
    proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" =>  "localhost", "port" => 3838) ) )
}
```

Unfortunately, this changed all the relative URLs as well so that any image in `http://raspi.home/shiny/index.html` is searched in `http://raspi.home/images/image.png` instead of `http://raspi.home/shiny/images/image.png`. Therefore, no resource could be found.

If I remove the condition, the mapping is global so the app is usable, but since everything is mapped all other sites are now unusable. This is described in [this bug](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/164) but I couldn't make the solution provided work.

I tried with `"map-urlpath" => ( "/shiny(.*)$" => "/$1" )` but inexpectedly this throws a 404 error (with or without the condition).

### resources

Here are more resources that might be related/useful:

- [Proxy URL to different port via Lighttpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/908132/proxy-url-to-different-port-via-lighttpd)
- [Lighttpd proxy redirect by port](https://serverfault.com/questions/441472/lighttpd-proxy-redirect-by-port)
- https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy
- https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/1946 (redirection worked though)
- [Rewrite URL before passing to proxy Lighttpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/135770/rewrite-url-before-passing-to-proxy-lighttpd)
- https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/8322

They didn't work for me, either because I didn't put the code on the right place or not adapted to my case, who knows...

Comment: I've put a lot of effort to make a good question with details, why would someone downvote it without even telling how to improve?

Comment: Please share concrete setup that you have tried, and what were the concrete issues with the setup.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Here is my best shot so far, in the edit. 2 days ago, there was unfortunately no setup that worked enough to be presentable here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/shiny" {
    proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" =>  "192.168.1.138", "port" => 3838 ) ) )
}
```

Delete `proxy.header` until you better understand what it does and does not do.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy

`proxy.header` `"map-urlpath"` will modify the request-line of the HTTP headers, but lighttpd does not rewrite the response body, so your R-shiny server will have to understand it is rooted under /shiny/.  I have not looked at R-shiny to see if that is possible.

A different alternative is to create DNS names shiny.raspi.home and homeassistant.raspi.home, which you can then configure lighttpd to reverse proxy

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "shiny.raspi.home" {
    proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" =>  "192.168.1.138", "port" => 3838 ) ) )
}
```

Please note that I changed the target `"port"` in my examples above, as I am guessing that is the reverse-proxy target host and port to which you would like lighttpd to reverse-proxy the request to http://shiny.raspi.home/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to have a configuration that is totally independent of the target if possible, so that the Shiny server remains accessible from its own address as well. Also, I messed up when writing my comment, the shiny-server is at localhost on a different port (but I intend to do it with 192.168.1.138::80 as well).

Comment: However, the DNS names `shiny.raspi.home` works very well, thanks! This is not what I intend to do but it is definitely a workaround solution.

Comment: You said that "lighttpd does not rewrite the response body", couldn't I use `map-host-response` for this? I tried but didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: lighttpd `proxy.header` mappings apply to HTTP request-line and HTTP response headers such as `Location`, but do not apply to the response **body**.  (Note the word "header" in `proxy.header` directive is distinct from the word "body".)

Comment: I'm sorry not to understand fast enough but it felt like the *body* was a bit modified, since all URLs were rewritten.

Comment: Check the HTML source code of the response in your client browser to see URL links.  Using relative-path urls in the response body is quite portable.